# How to send data from one view controller to SWReveal Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

in my application i want send data from registration view controller to login view controller and login view controller to SWRevealViewController. i am sending like this in RegistrationViewController,
In my login View Controller i created the NSString like this

```
"@property (nonatomic) NSString *login;"
```

In my RegistrationViewController getting string like this,

```
UIStoryboard *user = self.storyboard;
            LoginViewController *vc = [user instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];
            vc.login = @"1";
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in my SWRevealViewController created string like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *isMenu;
```

But i am not getting that string into my LoginViewController.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SWRevealViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:ivc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here i am attaching my image

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS SWRevealViewController - pass data between controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659343/ios-swrevealviewcontroller-pass-data-between-controllers)

Comment: In that they are using navigation controller.in my application not using that.

Comment: you don't need to do any extra procedure. just pass as you pass in another view controller. moreover, give more detail in your question how you are passing. like, where you defined strong property and where you synthesize etc. you can also use nsuserdefault.

Comment: @BadalShah. see my updated question.

Comment: you don't want to use nsuserdefault ?

Comment: @BadalShah.no i don't want to use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103917/discussion-between-mangi-reddy-and-badal-shah).